# Accessing theme of parent from iframe

Tags: web-applications, iframe

I have a Web application that is accessed via iframe, with user login.

It does detect the user login and conforms accordingly.

So how could I integrate the look and feel (or theme) of the parent page into the Web app?

Thanks.

Comment: why u use ifram ? not a new window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean something like:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Page on foo.com</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://bar.com/login"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

and you want bar.com/login to look like foo.com, that's impossible without foo.com's cooperation.  You won't be able to access the foo DOM from your iframe, as that would be cross-domain scripting.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control of the page being loaded in the iframe you can add a reference to one of the parent's css files.